# Show pivot columns

Tags: mikro-orm

I have 3 tables

**accounts**

- id
- account

**accounts_has_devices**

- account_id
- device_id
- status
- is_master

**devices**

- id
- name
- info

The **accounts_has_devices** aka pivot has some information about the device associated to the user, and the **device** table has info to the device itself:

exist a way to get the pivot data + device ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have more columns than the FKs in your pivot table, it is no longer a pivot table. You need to model this as three entities, not two.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/composite-keys/#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata